# Use custom map in Apache Superset Dashboard

Tags: geojson, shapefile, apache-superset

Superset dashboards currently supports standard country maps (geojson) with ISO Codes.

What would be the best way to import a custom map (like a forest map or an ocean map for example...) in order to display it on a Superset Dashboard?

P.S. : the custom map in question is in Shapefile format